# После запроса текста страницы выдает битый текст

Tags: python, requests, post, get

Пишу телеграмм бота для регистрации на сайте посольства рф, после get запроса, в нем содержится такой текст.

```
UG�m�^ˏ����Gm��Z�1�=:L-�W�"��?d_����x�b<֫E�@�xK���~[�DGԖ�~Fc�Jq%��S�?��&���Y�$�uW*�
�$FDK˼��K]���:����P �K�'��c�Na�)�����p����'0����o��'_��"U�M.~yS.�z,�������K��X��'�;
i�����+��N����#����,���Ԃh=]B
ŗ�\��Γ���ا��3�.�
�Q�����^�Y�߽lUg�����q��uynhQ��Q�m�u�j0��ځa>�m��d�mq#�e%Ӣz,�ƅ{��µβ��Rj���B��j|Nt���7�˅nz_�<�����v���Q���r���������?����i����v^IUð@�V�9ZZ
am�c����)D�<�|ʏ�bN�c�c�o^�L��t+�LGkg�)�r��F��H5L�5
��(�-�F�YG�1�X`�c�~8��"|�#���0���Uut�R�   �5����k"�1d+���g���,��+.�F��x�������:�ѱ�M�ޓ�b��I���s��r�1��)�9l)B��B̹������
��  �S;�Y�'�S?ҕު�����w�ټ���c����&��%��q�j����,��c�����yl��]�v�l[���#��'�����:*�/e%��n�P�B��v��?e��{�G��]i�}�>��n��5ƶ
�6U�k��@�DZ�~&<$ĺ��S�c��E��1�y�8�{�x��� *��bi���gi[�Z�G>����vC�w�_�?3B;��qf�+�;Xk*�s�Ο�8ݪ¹��]�݇�t��_� U��?�'��E��L&!-����r��
^�֎���.��*�)
��Db��LkcdH�hz�om�_�V4*���_0�w���yU��
�)��@O[�/5"��7щ�O�DliĒ��\��d�Z�x�v�P�&>-�R�w$�-��I|�������=o2t�� ��D�(� t+;�kU4�
����/�E~�)�2
�<5mL8��j��H�&�?(����M)����h��nSe�!��#Zµ{]�%����Y|��&õ�N�����F&���&���6!�O�Q-���6*0�k{ulp�W{A�1��R~�B���!ޭ�z���c2�ך���A�ɸ�[J�k� �׆!^!����&��R�
�{ū+ Q����޸_�hsH�u=�fbE�����<�b�ҍɤ�� �@��)�4���%?G̏3₿/�����,���y=@��
���i�v!���I%�1M�h�!�$-j8D�vw���)` ����jq��p�.G���/���>pgn>�V�#�A���i1�������v�k�*
$[����$]
�L�Q��J5�W��8��%�V���6�N��LT]\����~m�7HV��#���+m�=�;�q���v��&�X����#~$CE��7�F�~uBZ��1̌-�o�f9?PE����*�/W��
�������P����I?B�E��S��p�ni���k���G<D�%?YO6�[.:�����p�Մ�`�p�`�\���L.�n����{~��   kh��KǄ����~�a��������O����㜀������y�o����Hx�>x�2����g�z���%�K[��^�L';S��惷���e�,��&=�|�q����Zb����������7B�>UI��h�X�����߳�,[x�`�ܫ�� �R��S;d�L�4_(��ʁ�R
�^px��/L��%�~�ǹ(��]�np:@#޽:2p�{��̟j�]Rqk�_�TG��s�;y�Z*0�q_�q
```

Что это может быть? И почему?

Код:

```
import requests
import base64
import time
from config import *
import fake_useragent
import json

session = requests.Session()



country_id = 'ba07e47c-0ce5-73a2-602a-a2e18bb0d45e'
sp_id = '6e81fff3-710d-e74b-7e66-c947a922c5e1'
email = 'vafac51031@avucon.com'
password = 'Mt4a5GX'

user_agent = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
url = 'https://q.midpass.ru/ru/'
key = CAPTCHA_TOKEN
captcha_url = 'https://q.midpass.ru/ru/Account/CaptchaImage?1702476596227'
headers = {'user-agent': user_agent,
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
           'Accept-Language': 'ru',
           'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=sidm0twcuaam4u4deo5emvlu; cookiesConsentDate=1702471814250; .ASPXAUTH=91A11BAEF9862D0E7705B382FF1770801ABF0938E04A8DC283563BDDC5896D10D3172034DD3F7C14034EA4124650C92BF214866573E31987A067168985C2EFFC5518E18F57D0AD42C4BB0DB5FC9CEB10C6FF0A8F1425C71A7905ECDA63A770A652EE310EFE6ED101DC14995384840B4B58601D8500D02927E0E3CE3715455AC9FCD8E42E49C20C76342664B20A9366B8900FD004',
           'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
           'Content-Length': '233',
           'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Origin': 'https://q.midpass.ru',
           'Referer': 'https://q.midpass.ru/',
           'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
           'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
           'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
           'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
           'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
           'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
           'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
           'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
           }

response = requests.get(captcha_url)

ee = base64.b64encode((response.content))
payload = {'key': key, 'method': 'base64', 'body': ee, 'vernet': '2'}
r = requests.post("http://api.cap.guru/in.php", data=payload)
# Бывает :(
time.sleep(7.5)

rt = r.text.split('|')
url = 'http://api.cap.guru/res.php?key='+key+'&id='+rt[1]
response = requests.get(url)
captcha = str(response.content).split('|')[1][:-1]
print(captcha)

data = {'Email': email, 'Password': password, 'CountryId': country_id, 'ServiceProviderId':sp_id, 'Captcha': captcha,
        'NeedShowBlockWithServiceProviderAndCountry': True}

with open('proxy.json') as file:
    proxy_base = json.load(file)['https']
    for proxy in proxy_base:
        proxies = {
            'http://': proxy,
            'https://': proxy
        }
        response_reg = session.post('https://q.midpass.ru/ru/Account/DoPrivatePersonLogOn', data=data, headers=headers)
        index = session.get('https://q.midpass.ru/ru/Home/Index?_=1702733456924', data=data, headers=headers)
        print(index.text)
        break
```

Comment: `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',` - так может ответ запакованный приходит? )

Comment: Как пометить комментарий ответом? @CrazyElf

Comment: Никак. Надо написать именно ответ. Напишите свой ответ, только чуть подробнее - с тем, как вы исправили, чтобы заработало.